# How to use a component scoped function to set the initialState of useReducer using init in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I pass a function scoped within a component to the initializer function of useReducer?

I.E. how do I pass the component scoped function `handleButtonClick` into the `createInitialState` initializer for useReducer?

```
function createInitialState(buttonProps) {
  return {
    ...buttonProps,
    onClick: () => handleButtonClick, // function from component scope here
  };
}

const Component = ({ buttonProps }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, buttonProps, createInitialState);

  function handleButtonClick() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**extra credit:** Is it bad practice to declare the initializer inside the component scope as well? Every example of useReducer I've seen declares the reducer, initialState, and/or init outside of the component scope

Comment: Why shiuld the event handler be part of the state?

Comment: This is a simplistic example for illustration but I have a need to handle the events in the component in a deeply nested object that changes based on state.

Just wondering if this singular use case is possible and how it would be.

Comment: I think that you're looking for a solution to your solution to a problem, and not to the actual problem. Can you expend the example, and include the original problem?